# SAS Transpose Comma Separated Field

Tags: sas

This is a follow-up to an earlier question of mine.
[Transposing Comma-delimited field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363512/transposing-comma-delimited-field)

The answer I got worked for the specific case, but now I have a much larger dataset, so reading it in a datalines statement is not an option. I have a dataset similar to the one created by this process:

```
data MAIN;
    input ID STATUS STATE $;
cards;
123 7 AL,NC,SC,NY
456 6 AL,NC
789 7 ALL
;
run;
```

There are two problems here:
1: I need a separate row for each state in the STATE column
2: Notice the third observation says 'ALL'.  I need to replace that with a list of the specific states, which I can get from a separate dataset (below).

```
data STATES;
    input STATE $;
cards;
AL
NC
SC
NY
TX
;
run;
```

So, here is the process I am attempting that doesn't seem to be working.
First, I create a list of the STATES needed for the imputation, and a count of said states.

```
proc sql;
    select distinct STATE into :all_states separated by ','
    from STATES;
    select  count(distinct STATE) into :count_states
    from STATES;
quit;
```

Second, I try to impute that list where the 'ALL' value appears for STATE. This is where the first error appears.  How can I ensure that the variable STATE is long enough for the new value?   Also, how do I handle the commas?

```
data x_MAIN;
    set MAIN;
    if STATE='ALL' then STATE="&all_states.";
run;
```

Finally, I use a SCAN function to read in one state at a time.  I'm also getting an error here, but I think fixing the above part may solve it.

```
data x_MAIN_mod;
    set x_MAIN;
    array state(&count_states.) state:;
    do i=1 to dim(state);
        state(i) = scan(STATE,i,',');
    end; 
run;
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are almost there.  Try this on the last Data Step.

```
data x_MAIN_mod;
    set x_MAIN;
    format out_state $2.;
    nstate = countw(state,",");
    do i=1 to nstate;
       out_state = scan(state,i,",");
       output;
    end; 
run;
```

Comment: Thanks DomPazz. This doesn't completely solve the length issue, as ID 789 is missing SC, TX. Is there a way to force the data statement to read the whole length of the macro into x_main?

Comment: Redefine the length of STATE.  `data x_main; format STATE $<big number here>.;set main;...run;`  Usually when you see truncation, it's because the length of the variable is not high enough.

Comment: If it is in that they are in STATE, but not OUT_STATE, try `out_state = trim(scan(...));` to remove white space.

Comment: Yeah...was trying to avoid just putting in a big number in there.  I was able to do it with a macro statement.  %let length_state=%sysevalf(3*&count_states.-1);

%put &count_states.;
%put &length_state.;

data x_MAIN;
 length STATE $ &length_state.;
 set MAIN;
 if STATE='ALL' then STATE="&all_states.";
run;

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to actually have two steps like that?  You can use a 'big number' in a temporary variable and not have much effect on things, if you don't have the intermediate dataset.

```
data x_MAIN;
    length state_temp $150;
    set MAIN;
    if STATE='ALL' then STATE_temp="&all_states.";
    else STATE_temp=STATE;
    array state(&count_states.) state:;
    do i=1 to dim(state);
        state(i) = scan(STATE,i,',');
    end; 
    drop STATE_temp;
run;
```

If you actually *do* need the STATE, then honestly I'd go with the big number (=50*3, so not all *that* big) and then add `OPTIONS COMPRESS=CHAR;` which will (give or take) turn your `CHAR` fields into `VARCHAR` (at the cost of a tiny bit of CPU time, but usually far less than the disk read/write time saved).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.   I can definitely combine these two steps...I had just separated them during debugging.