# SAS retrieving values from row

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I want to retrieve row level values (Loans associated with account number) from a SAS table -
Please find below example.

[image]

Input

```
Account Number  Loans
123             abc, def, ghi
456             jkl, mnopqr, stuv
789             w, xyz
```

Output

```
Account Numbers Loans
123             abc
123             def
123             ghi
456             jkl
456             mnopqr
456             stuv
789             w
789             xyz
```

Loans are separated by commas and they don't have fix length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAS Transpose Comma Separated Field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358093/sas-transpose-comma-separated-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `countw()` to count the number of values on a line and `scan()` to pick them out.

Both have a last optional variable to specify the separator, which in your case is `,`.

```
data Loans (keep= AccountNo Loan);
    infile datalines truncover;
    Input @1 AccountNo 3. @17 LoanList $250.;
    if length(LoanList) gt 240 then put 'WARNING: You might need to extend Loans';

    label AccountNo = 'Account Number' Loan = 'Loans';
    do loanNo = 1 to countw(LoanList, ',');
        Loan = scan(LoanList, loanNo, ',');
        output;
    end;
    datalines;
123             abc, def, ghi
456             jkl, mnopqr, stuv
789             w, xyz
;

proc print data=Loans label noobs;
run;
```

## The reverse operation requires different techniques.

To enable `by AccountNo` processing, we must first construct a SAS dataset from the input and then read that back in with a `set` statement.

```
data Loans;
    infile datalines;
    input @1 AccountNo 3. @5 Loan $25.;
    datalines;
123 15-abc 
123 15-def 
123 15-ghi 
456 99-jkl 
456 99-mnopqr 
456 99-stuv 
789 77-w 
789 77-xyz
;
data LoanLists;
    set Loans;
    by AccountNo;
```

Now create your Loanlist long enough and overwrite the default behaviour of SAS to re-initialise all variables for every observation (=row of data).

```
    format Loanlist $250.;
    retain Loanlist;
```

Collect all loans for an account, separating them with comma an blank.

```
    if first.AccountNo then Loanlist = Loan;
    else Loanlist = catx(', ',Loanlist,Loan);
    if length(LoanList) gt 240 then put 'WARNING: you might need to extend LoanList';
```

Keep only the full list per account.

```
    if last.AccountNo;
    drop Loan;
proc print;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, countw and scan function did work

Comment: Please let me know what if I want to reverse the process?

Comment: Accepting or up-voting my answer would help.

Comment: Input 2

 AccountNumbers  Loans
123             15-abc
123             15-def
123             15-ghi
456             99-jkl
456             99-mnopqr
456             99-stuv
789             77-w
789             77-xyz

   
Output 2

 AccountNumber   Loans
123                       15-abc, 15-def, 15-ghi
456                       99-jkl, 99-mnopqr, 99-stuv
789                       77-w, 77-xyz